# How to use access messages from your passportjs strategy in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js, message, flash-message

If you have a react application and don't wanna use `connect-flash` to access the messages generated by the local strategy you can use the following:

My passport local strategy, I am using a sqlite db:

```
 passport.use(
        new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'name' },
        (name, password, done) => {
            //Match user
            db.get(`SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name = '${name}'`, (err, user) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                if(!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message : 'Username not registered' });
                }
                //Match password
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if(err) throw Error;
                    if(isMatch) {
                        done(null, user, { message : 'Log in successful' });
                    } else {                        done(null, false, { message : 'Password incorrect' })
                    }
                });
            })
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom call back function for your /login route:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (!user) { return res.json(info); }
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.json(info);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

The info argument contains the object passed as a third argument in done() from the strategy and can be added to the body of res and therefore used by react.